# Synclock a section of code while waiting for ShowDialog to return

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, synchronization, synclock

I'm having trouble working out how to lock my application out of a section of code while it waits for a response from an external program

I've used `Synclock` on a section of code with the `Me` object in the expression. In this `Synclock` I call an overridden `ShowDialog` method of a dialog box, which has a timeout parameter, but does return the value from the underlying `ShowDialog` function call ,once the timer is setup. Works like this.

```
    SyncLock Me
        Dim frmDlgWithTimeout As New frmDlgWithTimeout ' dialog box with overridden ShowDialog '
        Dim res As DialogResult = frmDlgWithTimeout.ShowDialog(10 * 1000) ' 10 sec timeout '
    End SyncLock
```

Now, external programs may raise events that bring my application to this `Synclock` but it doesn't prevent it from entering it, even though the `ShowDialog` function hasn't returned a value (and hence what I thought would keep the section of code locked).

There is only one instance of the object that is used for lock in the program.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally do not use the synchlock functionality of VB.NET as I have found it to be finicky.  I like to create a form scope boolean say:

```
dim lock as boolean = false
```

I then utilize this boolean as my synchlock, as in the below example.

```
 Sub LockUntilShowDialogOkSelected()
    If Not lock Then
      lock = True
      Dim frmDlgWithTimeout As SaveFileDialog ' dialog box with overridden ShowDialog '

      If frmDlgWithTimeout.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        lock = False
      End If
    End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: I do agree with this method because SyncLock is used on the same Process with multiple threads.  Not in different processes.